# With this AJAX request is it possible to post data to different id's

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I currently have an AJAX request which posts data from the database into a `<div>` tag with the id of `result`. Within my PHP query I return `*` the data from my db table `module` and then return the specific values to a `<div>` with the id of `result`. However, is there any way that I can post other data from my PHP statement and fill out various id's within my html?

For example the  with the id of `result` shows the module ID and name, however I wanted to also have another  with the id tag of `content` and return the content data from my db and just send to that id of `content` Is it possible to fill different  with different data with the same AJAX request?

**module.php**

```
<div>
    <h1>Welcome to this module</h1>
        <div id="result"> 
        <!-- This is where I currently return the ID and the module name -->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        <!-- This is where I would like to return other data via the AJAX -->
        </div>
</div>
```

**moduleTestingAJAX.php:**

```
<?php

require 'scripts/db.php';

$moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];

if(isset($_POST['moduleID']))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM `module` WHERE moduleID = ?");    
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $moduleID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['moduleID'].' '.$row['moduleName'];
        }
    }
     ?>
    </div>
```

**script.js:**

```
function getModuleData(moduleID){
    console.log(moduleID);
    $.ajax({  
        url: "moduleTestingAJAX.php",  
        method: "post",   
        data: {moduleID:moduleID},
        success: function(data){  
              $('#result').html(data);    
        }  
    });  

  console.log('test');
}
```

Screenshot after using Nabil's answer as you can see the returned data is in one line, whereas the content data should be returned to the line below:
[image: output]

Comment: You can't use two ajax?

Comment: Ok, do you know how within the same AJAX query I could post the data of `content` which is also pulled out via the same PHP query, into another <div> ?

Comment: Give me an example

Comment: @SimoneRossaini so within the same ajax call I would want to also fill another div with data from the database, within the same call? so an id and a module name gets sent to the div with the id of result but in the same ajax call can I also fill other data to another div with an id of `content`?

Comment: You must use json for control wich data output in js.

Comment: @Dharman secured :)

Comment: @T.C, check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php    and     https://www.formget.com/jquery-post-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send back a json response with key as div id and value as the data need to be populated.

```
<?php

require 'scripts/db.php';

$moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];

if(isset($_POST['moduleID']))
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM `module` WHERE moduleID = ?");    
$stmt->bind_param("i", $moduleID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$output = [];
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $output["result"] = $row['moduleID'].' '.$row['moduleName'];
    $output["content"] = $row["content"];
    }

echo json_encode($output);

}
 ?>
</div>
```

Using jquery you can populated different divs from the reponse

```
function getModuleData(moduleID){
    console.log(moduleID);
    $.ajax({  
        url: "moduleTestingAJAX.php",  
        method: "post",   
        data: {moduleID:moduleID},
        success: function(data){  
              $('#result').html(data.result);    
              $('#content').html(data.content);    
        }  
    });  


}
```

Comment: Hi Nabil, so it does pull out the correct rows from the db however it doesn't quite place them where I need. I will update the question with the output of using this....